# Determine the largest and smallest values of Cov(X, Y)

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose $X$ ~ $Normal(0, 100)$ and $Y$ ~ $Binomial(80, 0.25)$
Determine (with explanation) the largest and smallest values of Cov(X, Y).

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives:

$\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)} \le Cov(X, Y) \le \sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}$

$-10\sqrt{15} \le Cov(X, Y) \le 10\sqrt{15}$

From the available information, can we deduce a tighter bound for Cov(X, Y)?
Also, other than Cauchy-Schwarz, is there any other explanation we could give for the bound on Cov(X, Y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat more generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with nonzero variances, 
$$\text{corr}(X,Y) = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\;\text{Var}(Y)}}$$ is the Pearson correlation of $X$ and $Y$.  It is always in the interval $[-1,1]$ (as implied by Cauchy-Schwarz).  It is $1$ iff $Y = aX + b$ almost surely for some constants $a$, $b$, with $a > 0$, and $-1$ if $Y = aX + b$ with $a < 0$.

In your example, 
 since $X$ is continuous while $Y$ is discrete, you certainly can't have such a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$, so $-1$ and $1$ are impossible: your lower and upper bounds are not tight.  However, numerically determining the exact maximum and minimum possible does not look easy. It seems to me that the greatest correlation will occur in the following situation: take $t_0, \ldots t_{79}$ such that $\mathbb P(X \le t_i)) = \mathbb P(Y \le i)$, $i=0\ldots 79$, $t_{-1} = -\infty$ and $t_{80} = \infty$, and then
given $X$ take $Y = i$ where $t_{i-1} < X \le t_i$.